# Supabase: Unable to validate email address: invalid format

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, supabase

I integrated supabase with react-native I followed this [article](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/with-expo#intro)
But I couldn't signUp

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
import { SUPABASE_URL, SUPABASE_ANON_KEY } from '../constants'

export const supabase = createClient(SUPABASE_URL, SUPABASE_ANON_KEY, {
  localStorage: AsyncStorage as any,
})

const signup = async (email, password)=>{
   const { user, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
        email,
        password,
    })
    if(error){
        console.log(error); 
        // Object {
        //  "message": "Unable to validate email address: invalid format",
        //  "status": 422,
        // }
        return
    }
    return user;
}
```

When I Invoke signup function it prints

> `Unable to validate email address: invalid format`

Comment: Can you try logging the email inside of your signup function to make sure it is formatted correctly?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue with `auth.generateLink`. It turned out that my arguments were in the wrong order.

Comment: Why are you explaining problem in answer? Check : [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer#:~:text=Make%20sure%20your%20answer%20provides,going%20in%20the%20right%20direction.)